# Redirect after email authentication

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I'm having trouble redirecting the user after successful login, i've read the documentation for Firebase and tried several things but no luck so far

Can anyone point me into the right direction ?

Thanks in advance,
Jérémie.

Here's the controller.js

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $state, Auth) {
$scope.data = {};

$scope.login = function() {
      Auth.login($scope.data.email, $scope.data.password).then(function() {
        $state.go("tab-discover");
               })

    .error(function() {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
            title: 'Mauvais identifiants',
            template: 'Veuillez recommencer'
        });
    });
}

$scope.signup = function() {
      Auth.signup($scope.data.email, $scope.data.password)
    .error(function() {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
            title: 'Erreur',
            template: 'Un probleme est survenu'
        });
      });
    }

  })
```

And the services.js

```
.factory("Auth", function(FURL, $firebaseAuth) {


  var ref = new Firebase(FURL);
  var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
  var Auth = {
    user: {},

login: function(email, password){
  console.log("loginService", email, password);

  return ref.authWithPassword({
    "email": email,
    "password": password
  }, function(error, authData) {


    if (error) {
    console.log("La connexion a echoué!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
  }
})
    },
    signup: function(email, password){
      console.log("signupService", email, password);
      return ref.createUser({
        "email": email,
        "password": password
      }, function(error, userData) {
  if (error) {
    switch (error.code) {
      case "EMAIL_TAKEN":
        console.log("The new user account cannot be created because the email is already in use.");
        break;
      case "INVALID_EMAIL":
        console.log("The specified email is not a valid email.");
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Error creating user:", error);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
  }
}).then(function(){
        return Auth.login(email, password);
    })
  }
}
return Auth;
})
```

Comment: Redirect, like `window.location = 'someotherlocation';`?

Comment: @Filipe OP is using angular routing to redirect, the $state.go(..) line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like firebase is using callbacks where you're trying to return it as a promise with `then`. A simple fix would be to pass a callback to your login function and call it inside the firebase callback:

```
login: function(email, password, callback, onError){
  console.log("loginService", email, password);

  ref.authWithPassword({
    "email": email,
    "password": password
  }, function(error, authData) {

  if (error) {
    onError(error);
  } else {
    callback(authData);
  }
})
```

Then call it like this:

```
Auth.login($scope.data.email, $scope.data.password, function (data) {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", data);
    $state.go("tab-discover");
}, function (error) {
    console.log("La connexion a echoué!", error);
});
```

Comment: i get 750853   error    TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.login (http://localhost:8100/js/controllers.js:7:62) and 751852   warn     FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: callback is not a function

Comment: I removed the then from the code, if you're getting that error it's not with the code I provided